# Migrate Authentication from JBoss EAP 6.4 to JBoss EAP 7.0

Tags: jboss-eap-7

During the migration process from JBoss EAP 6.4 to **JBoss EAP 7.0** we stumbled in a SSO authentication issue, in the previous version we used the class: **org.jboss.as.web.security.GenericHeaderAuthenticator** class

However, we can't use that in JBoss EAP 7.0, what's the solution to replace that?